# QGIS 2.6.0 minidump crash every time I save

Tags: qgis, minidump

Just got QGIS 2.6.0 running on Windows 7 service pack 1 64 bit. Project loads, edits, saves editing changes, adds removes, layers no problem. Only problem is saving the project. Do that and it's certain death. You get a mini dump crash error.

Then you attempt to open the project again and it says unexpected end of file at line'x' and shows the file as being 0 KB.  Restore the project to a previous version and it happens again EVERY TIME.  This also happened when I upgraded to 2.4.  What gives? Yes, going to be writing a bug ticket also.

Comment: I see this minidump too - ticket was closed http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10756

Comment: I had previously tried all those suggestions and nothing worked. Is this the new norm every time a new version comes out or what?

Comment: We had similar problems after updating to 2.6. One thing you can try is to open the project in 2.6 and save it under a new file name, instead of saving to the same file. Also, we've since switched to the development version (2.7), which seems more stable in this regard.

Comment: Did you try removing all your plugins?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107617/why-does-qgis-2-4-crash-at-every-shutdown

Comment: The same here. Win 7 Pro x64 with Qgis 2.6.0. Uninstall of Metasearch Catalog Client plugin solved the problem.

Comment: I had this same issue with QGIS 2.12 and 2.14.  The solution for me was below.

Comment: Same occurs here in 2.14 in Windows 8 when trying to export in .pdf format. When I got any transparency aplied to a layer, it shuts down at saving. Without the transparency it saves.

Answer (score 6):

I have had this problem with each generation of QGIS and windows 7,8, and 10
Today I solved it!!!
I deleted the .qgis2 folder in my user path
Simple as that.
When QGIS opened it created a new .qgis folder and will now happily and gracefully exit. :-)

Comment: Its works !!! but you need to re-install necessary plugins..

Comment: This was happening with QGIS 2.12 and 2.14.  I'm running them on Win10, 64bit.  Deleting the .qgis2 folder worked for me.  It seems I should delete this folder whenever I install a new version of QGIS...

Comment: I had this issue on 2.18 primarily when zooming in and out on print composer.  Deleting the .qgis2 folder seems to have worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There were some issues with QGIS 2.6 crashing with old projects and the print composer:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10756

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11685

You can try the latest dev build, which has some bugs fixed, or take the bugfix release 2.6.1 which is just released.

Creating a new project from scratch should be save.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on QGIS 2.6 64 bit on Windows 7 Home Premium with all current updates.

Crashed on saving, every time, minidump and project file saved as 0 kb file or with small invalid file.

Uninstalled metasearch catalog client and solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted `.qgis2\python\plugins` and eveything went just fine. Removing everything would make me lose recent projects list, custom expressions/functions/scripts which I rather keep.

Comment: What plugins did you have before?