# Completely uninstalling and removing QGIS 2.8.1 on Windows Vista

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2, windows

I want to uninstall and completely remove QGIS installation from my computer (Windows Vista). I have uninstalled it and when i try to reinstall it says it is already installed on the system.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make sure all folders in your hard drive and your `.qgis2` folder (`C:/Users/You/.qgis2`) are deleted. You could also delete the Registry entries for QGIS by running the **regedit** program and searching for *QGIS*:

[image: QGIS registry]

Hopefully when you restart your computer, you will be able to reinstall QGIS again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked and i have reinstalled successfully.

Comment: @mapperx - Brilliant buddy! Glad you got it working =)

Answer (score 8):

There are comprehensive uninstall programs available which do thorough searches and removal for all leftover files and registry values which should solve the problem. An example is Revo Uninstaller.