# QGIS crashes (dumped crash) while importing SHP layers or SpatialLite

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, spatialite

I meet problems with the last version of QGIS (Lyon 2.12.3) 64bits on Windows 7.

The software crashes as soon as I load a SHP layer or use SpatiaLite layers (created from OSM data).

[image]

Besides, each time I open QGIS desktop, I get the following error message:

[image]

I tried to uninstall/install again the software, to empty all directories with QGIS stuffs, to empty temp directories, nothing changes.

Moreover, even after unstalling QGIS, when I try to install it again, I get the message that QGIS is still installed on my computer.

I cannot use the app anymore...

Does anyone could help me ?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to completely uninstall and remove QGIS 2.8.1?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. I tried to uninstall/install QGIS the way it is described in the post but it didn't work... I also tried to install an older version of QGis but it still doesn't work. It's probably a OS system but QGis works very well on my laptop which runs also with Windows 7...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem came from the 64bits version of QGIS. I installed QGIS 32bits instead of 64bits and everything works.