# QGIS corrupted plugins upon reinstallation

Tags: qgis, python-2.7, qgis-processing

I had various bugs in my GIS softwares (QGIS, ArcGIS) after uninstalling PyCharm from my computer (time limited school license). For a school assignment we had to change the PythonPATH and PythonHOME and after uninstalling the said IDE, some plugins stoped working in QGIS.

I uninstalled the programs, ran CCleaner to remove old registries and just re-installed these:

- ArcGIS 10.2
- OSGeo4W (including QGIS Lyon 2.12.3)
- OpenGeoSuite 4.8 (without QGIS)
- Python 2.7
- PyScripter

Now the Processing toolbox and other plugins are corrupted and there is this error message:

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'**

Also, when the program starts I have other Python errors.

**Impossible to load fTools plugin provokes error when calling classFactory()**

(translated from french)

Here's the logfile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 306, in startPlugin
                plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\fTools\__init__.py", line 33, in classFactory
                from .fTools import fToolsPlugin
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\fTools\fTools.py", line 52, in <module>
                import doRandom
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools\doRandom.py", line 37, in <module>
                import random
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Python27\Lib\random.py", line 49, in <module>
                import hashlib as _hashlib
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Python27\Lib\hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
                _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
            AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

Comment: Did you delete the `qgis2` folder (`C:\Users\You\.qgis2`) before reinstalling? This is where most of your plugins are stored are requires to be manually removed.

Comment: No, I was not aware of this procedure. I guess it's worth a try. Would you reccomend re-installing the full OSgeo4W bundle?

Comment: Remove old QGIS installations from "C:Program Files\" etc. Clean registry. Before reinstalling, remove .qgis2. from User path like Joseph said. You can try QGIS standalone installer.

Comment: @NinjaTuna - If you plan on using Python and various other packages then you could re-install via OSGeo4W but is not required if you just want to use QGIS as a standalone software.

Comment: @Joseph - I uninstalled OSGeo4W by deleting C:\OSGeo4W64, deleted the qgis2 folder as recommended, restarted the computer before re-installing OSGeo4W but the problem persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: @NinjaTuna - Try cleaning the registry keys as suggested by Artec, you can do this by checking this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1). If the problem is still there then my guess is that the problem lies with another program.

Comment: @Joseph - I deleted the 'C:\Osgeo4W folder' as well as the qgis2 folder ('C:\Users\Me\.qgis2'), deleted the registry in regedit and ran CCleaner to find other things linked to OSGeo4W. I restarted and re-installed but the problem persisted.

So with my basic Python skills I opened 'C:\Python27\Lib\hashlib.py' in Notepad++ and checked on line 138 (where the problem was specified) and compared it to the same file on the school's computers, where QGIS works correctly. I found 2 extra command lines that I commented out (using #) for the code to be like the one at the school. IT WORKED!

Comment: @NinjaTuna - Strange as to why those files were different in the first place but well done! You should post your comment as an answer and accept it (click the green-faded tick on the left-hand side when you posted your answer) as this shows your question has been solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning registries and re-installations did not solve the problem.

I opened `C:\Python27\Lib\hashlib.py` (the problematic file) in **Notepad++** and checked on line 138 (where the problem was specified) and compared it to the same file on an other computer, where QGIS works correctly.

**Note: I only edited the python file, not the compiled python file.**

I found 2 extra command lines that I commented out (using #) for the code to be like the one on the working computer.

I saved the file, re-opened QGIS and found no error and geoprocessing tool back.

Here are the 2 extra lines that I commented out in case someone else gets a similar problem:

(first line = 133)

```
try:
    import _hashlib
    new = __hash_new
    __get_hash = __get_openssl_constructor
#    algorithms_available = algorithms_available.union(
#        _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
except ImportError:
    new = __py_new
    __get_hash = __get_builtin_constructor
```

(last line = 141)

Comment: I only have basic python skills so I can't explain in much depth why it worked. I'll keep this thread updated in case further problems arise from editing the code.

Comment: New problem arose a few days later. Different error messages, details posted here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183095/qgis-corrupted-processing-tool