# Geoprocessing LineIntersections QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, intersection, qgis-processing, qgis-2.14

I am trying to make a QGIS plugin, and one of my goals is to use the geoprocessing tool "intersection" of QGIS into my Python code for the plugin.
When I run it directly into QGIS, it works perfectly (especially transferring all attributes of both layers intersected).

When I run it in Python code, the result is the same but the attribute table does not contain all attributes (only one attribute...).

Here is an extract of my code for this purpose:

```
processing.runandload("qgis:lineintersections", final_layer1, final_layer2, "", "", output_intersect_path)
```

I also tested:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:lineintersections", final_layer1, final_layer2, "", "", output_intersect_path)
intersect_temp = QgsVectorLayer(output_intersect_path, output_intersect, "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(intersect_temp)
```

The problem lies in the parameters: final_layer1 and final_layer2 or the layers intersected. Then, the source help says "Field A" and "Field B", but I do not know what to put for those parameters in order to get all attributes transfered...

Does someone know how to do that ?

---

Here is my code:

```
    layer1_field = "last_fieldName"
    layer2_field = "last_fieldName"

    ouput_0 = processing.runalg("qgis:lineintersections", final_layer1, final_layer2, None, None, None)
    output_1 = processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributestable", ouput_0['OUTPUT'], final_layer1, layer1_field, layer1_field, None)
    result = processing.runandload("qgis:joinattributestable", output_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'], final_layer2, layer2_field, layer2_field, None)
```

Don`t know why it is not good at all....

---

Here are the [source shapefiles](http://www.partage-fichiers.com/upload/uhj7dl7g/) to test.

Comment: Does anyone has a clue ?

Comment: You used the **Intersection** tool or the **Line intersections** tool directly from QGIS? They are both different tools, the first provides you with all attributes. The latter does not.

Comment: @Joseph : I used both, but Intersection tool does not create points intersection but lines intersection (my inputs are both lines)...

Comment: @Joseph : I want point intersection with all attributes (just like Intersect tool in ArcGIS..). Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem**

Indeed, the QGIS Lines Intersection algorithm doesn't preserve all fields. It is only capable of keeping one field from each line layer. Moreover, if the fields that you choose from layer1 and layer2 have the same name, the algorithm only keeps the first one (from layer1).

**Short term solution**

You can get an adjusted [Processing script for intersecting lines](https://github.com/gacarrillor/QGIS-Resources/blob/master/collections/processing_scripts/processing/Lines_Intersection.py) from my resource repository (https://github.com/gacarrillor/QGIS-Resources.git). Just install my scripts from the QGIS Resource Sharing plugin and you'll get the *Lines Intersection Keep All Fields* tool.

[image]

[image]

**Mid-term solution**

I've created a Pull Request (check it [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3664)) to fix this issue in Processing. It would enable you to get a field from each layer, all fields from both layers, or all fields from one layer and one field from the other.

Comment: +1, many thanks for this Germán! I tested this on the OP's source shapefiles and obtained all the fields. If the OP can confirm this works then I will award you the bounty ;)

Comment: When I want to use the short term solution, I appears an error reading the repositiory: "Error reading repository: German's QGIS Resources.Status code: 301 Moved Permanently"... Do you have a solution for this please ?

Comment: For the mid term solution, I saw on github your request, but what should I do in order to get the tool ?

Comment: Well, you could just download the [python script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gacarrillor/QGIS-Resources/master/collections/processing_scripts/processing/Lines_Intersection.py) (right click, Save Page As...) and add it directly to the Processing Toolbox by clicking on the "Add script from file" tool.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo : Thanks it works when running into QGIS. But what if I want to run it on my python plugin code ?

Comment: Go to the menu `Processing -> History` and you'll find how to run it from Python. An example: `processing.runalg("script:linesintersectionkeepallfields","/tmp/forum_layer/layer1.shp","/tmp/forum_layer/layer2.shp", False, "ID", False, "ID", None)`

Comment: MANY THANKS !!! It works finally ! Issue solved ! Many many thanks ! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: @GermánCarrillo : I have a trouble... I noticed that when I run the script (directly in Qgis or with Python) I do not get the same results as the "LineIntersections" tool on Qgis ! I get the Ids, but the correspondance is different ! For instance: ID 1129836 of layer1 matched with 1129326 with "LineIntersections" tool but matched with ID 1129313 with your script...

Comment: I also noticed that IDs resulting from your script do not corrispond to any of of the IDs of my second input (layer2)... Could you help me solve that please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47337/discussion-between-m-siret-and-german-carrillo).

Comment: To summarize the chat, the user was using 2 memory layers (never mentioned that in the post) which had the same source. As you may know, Processing uses the layer source almost as an id. In this case, Processing was not able to differentiate between both layers. I suggested to include a `memoryid` key in the memory URI (something like `LineString?crs=...&memoryid=1)`, as Processing does. It didn't seem to work for the user, although I tested the whole thing with a piece of code the user shared with me and everything worked fine. 1010 features, like the original algorithm.

Comment: @m.siret - It is unfortunate that your problem still persists but I can confirm that both answers from Germán and myself do seem to work for us (I checked over a dozen points and the attributes from the intersecting lines matched correctly). I will award the bounty and I suggest that you wipe QGIS completely (including the [registry keys](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1)) and install the latest QGIS version. And then adapt your plugin to any changes and try this solution again.

Answer (score -1):

You could try deleting the processing folder in your .qgis2 path and run the line intersection tool in qgis 2.16.

This is because qgis 2.16 uses processing as core so you dont need the one in the .qgis2 path. It uses the processing folder in the same place you installed qgis 2.16.

Comment: I want to run it through Python in my plugin... Why should I delete this folder ?

Comment: I do not have processing plugin... I have a processing folder but not a processing plugin folder

Comment: @m.siret - Try removing the _processing_ folder from `/.qgis2/python/plugins/`, load QGIS 2.16 and your layers and run the code. If you still do not get the same results I did, I will add a bounty as I am unsure what the problem could be...

Comment: @Joseph I do not have any folder processing in the path you told me ! In the folder "plugins", I have my plugins not processing...

Comment: @m.siret - In that case, I'm not sure what else is the problem so will provide a bounty in the hope that others could see where the issue lies.

Comment: The problem comes from lineintersection process in Python.. I do not get both Ids ... Just one field instead of 2.