# What's a good way to implement an 'Attributes to keep' option in a QGIS processing script?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

I'm working on a processing script that selects features by their spatial relationship. The result is a virtual layer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# define interface
##Virtual Layers (QGIS 2.x)=group
##Select by spatial relationship=name
##Layer_to_select_from=vector
##Spatial_relationship=selection Intersects;Contains;Within;Touches;Overlaps;Equals
##Intersection_layer=vector
##True_or_false=selection True;False
##Snapping_tolerance=string 1e-5
##Output_layer=string vl_
##Output_unique_identifier_column=string gid
##Output_geometry_column=string geom

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry

# get input parameters from GUI
inlayer_select = processing.getObject(Layer_to_select_from)

spatial_rs = Spatial_relationship
if spatial_rs == 0:
    spatial_rs = 'ST_Intersects'
elif spatial_rs == 1:
    spatial_rs = 'ST_Contains'
elif spatial_rs == 2:
    spatial_rs = 'ST_Within'
elif spatial_rs == 3:
    spatial_rs = 'ST_Touches'
elif spatial_rs == 4:
    spatial_rs = 'ST_Overlaps'
elif spatial_rs == 5:
    spatial_rs = 'ST_Equals'

inlayer_intersection = processing.getObject(Intersection_layer)

t_or_f = True_or_false
snaptolerance = Snapping_tolerance

outlayer = Output_layer
outuic = Output_unique_identifier_column
outgeom = Output_geometry_column

# get geometry type and coordinate reference system from input layer ('Layer to select from')
ingeomtype = inlayer_select.geometryType()
if ingeomtype == 0:
    ingeomtype = 'point'
elif ingeomtype == 1:
    ingeomtype = 'linestring'
elif ingeomtype == 2:
    ingeomtype = 'polygon'

incrs = inlayer_select.crs().authid()
incrs = incrs[5:]

# create query
query_t = """SELECT
    DISTINCT('{0}'.rowid) AS '{4}',
    '{0}'.geometry AS '{5}'/*:{6}:{7}*/
FROM '{0}', '{2}'
WHERE {1}(ST_Snap('{0}'.geometry, '{2}'.geometry, {3}), ST_Snap('{2}'.geometry, '{0}'.geometry, {3}));
""".format( inlayer_select.name(), spatial_rs, inlayer_intersection.name(), snaptolerance, outuic, outgeom, ingeomtype, incrs )

query_f = """SELECT
    '{0}'.rowid AS '{4}',
    '{0}'.geometry AS '{5}'/*:{6}:{7}*/
FROM '{0}' LEFT JOIN '{2}'
ON {1}(ST_Snap('{0}'.geometry, '{2}'.geometry, {3}), ST_Snap('{2}'.geometry, '{0}'.geometry, {3}))
WHERE '{2}'.rowid IS NULL;
""".format( inlayer_select.name(), spatial_rs, inlayer_intersection.name(), snaptolerance, outuic, outgeom, ingeomtype, incrs )

if t_or_f == 0:
    query = query_t
elif t_or_f == 1:
    query = query_f

# run query and add layer to map
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), outlayer, "virtual" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

[image]

Here is a short screencast if someone wants to see the script in action: http://hub.qgis.org/attachments/10767/select_by_spatial_relationship.mp4

At the moment the GUI misses an 'Attributes to keep' option. As far as I know there is no parameter type to list the attributes of an input layer as checkboxes (see http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html and http://hub.qgis.org/issues/16348). Would an input field (type `string`), that is designed to accept a comma separted list, do the job? Can anyone help me to implement an 'Attributes to keep' option in a smooth way?

Comment: Perhaps the answer from Germán Carrillo in this post might help: [Geoprocessing LineIntersections QGIS Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213460/geoprocessing-lineintersections-qgis-python) where he made a script which allows you to keep a field from both layers.

Comment: Implementing a 'Keep all fields' checkbox is a good idea, but a comma separated list would be more flexible (see  'PostGIS geoprocessing tools' plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Fields of the input layer

[image]

If you use `field` instead of `string`

```
##Layer_to_select_from=vector
##Output_unique_identifier_column= field Layer_to_select_from
```

You can choose one of the fields of the input layer (only one)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can be solved by some Python similar to this:

```
string = 'att-1, att_2, att3,'

# remove space
string = string.replace(' ', '')

# remove ',' at start/end
if string[:1] == ',':
    string = string[1:]

if string[len(string)-1] == ',':
    string = string[:-1]

# convert string in list
string = string.split(',')

# put attributes in quotes
string = ['\"' + string + '\"' for string in string]

# print attributes
print ',\n' + ',\n'.join(string)

#SQL: ... AS "geom"
,
"att-1",
"att_2",
"att3"
#SQL: FROM ...
```

Aliases are not supported yet.