# Problem merging polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, merge, features

I've got a polygon shapefile with 11 features (11 Italian cities) and I want them to merge them into one, however I cannot activate the "Merge selected features" button.

Any suggestion about the reason?

Mind that the project SR and the layer SR are the same and I already verified the topology.

I attach a snapshot of the viewer and a link to download the shapefile.

[image: Snapshot of the viewer]
[Download the shapefile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23997272/comuni_merge.zip)

Comment: I downloaded your dataset, opened it with QGIS 2.14.1, and successfully merged them with the merge selected features tool in the advanced digitizing toolbar

Comment: I'm working with 2.18: maybe it's a bug of the Qgis version?

Comment: You may try closing your current project, open a new QGIS project and load ONLY the shapefile "comuni merge". Edit mode, select the 11 features in the attribute table, and then Merge (a table will pop-up you need to select one of the features). The Merge button looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kfqIA.png

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, but the "Merge selected features" remains frozen, as you can see here:[link](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23997272/snap.png)

Comment: Close ALL QGIS instances, and try open it again with qgis 2.14.2 (in the second screenshot I can see you have two versions of QGIS opened)

Comment: Done it... doesn't change at all. Maybe I should delete both the versions and re-install both of them?

Comment: Give it a try. But re-install only a clean version of the latest QGIS release.

Comment: I merged the polygons in QGIS 2.18. Could the problem be with the file permissions? Try saving the file to a different folder and try merging the second shape file.

Comment: I tried to uninstall both Qgis 2.18 and 2.14 and Python and to re-install only 2.18 brand new. Tried also to move to another directory. But the "Merge features" keeps to be frozen. Is there a way to re-install the ftools module? Once it was a good way out of this sort of issues...

Comment: Try to completely remove and install QGIS using osgeo4w: https://www.qgis.org/it/site/forusers/download.html (advanced users). You can read this (in italian), hope it helps: http://lists.gfoss.it/pipermail/gfoss/2012-May/022851.html .And also this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1.

Comment: Can you try the dissolve tool instead?