# Opening vector files in QGIS 2.18 causes error and crash

Tags: qgis, installation, error, vector-tiles

When trying to open vector files (.shp or .tab) in QGIS 2.18 and 2.18.3 on my desktop using either drag and drop or through Add Layer, I get the "qgis-bin.exe has stopped working" message and crashes. Otherwise QGIS appears to open without problems.
If I open a raster file (.ecw or .tab) I can then open the vector and display it without a problem. Strange.

I have tried:

a) Reinstalling both 2.18 and 2.18.3 on the desktop

b) Using older version 2.14 on desktop - everything appears to work fine with same files

c) Checking 2.18.3 on my laptop - everything appears to work fine

2.18 was working well on the desktop until I upgraded to 2.18.3 however this version seems to be ok on the laptop so doesn't appear to be the programme. Have never had this issue before over the years of installing QGIS as usually installs seamlessly so has got me a bit baffled and annoyed. May be something obvious?

Further to this (64bit version, with or without GRASS):

1) Browser works fine

2) If I remove the raster and leave the vector, it crashes. If I have the raster and add 2 vectors, it's fine. If I remove 1 vector, it's fine, if I remove the other vector leaving the raster, it's fine. If I have 2 vectors and remove raster it's fine. If I then remove 1 vector leaving 1 vector it's fine. If I remove everything it's fine. If I then load vector again, it crashes.

Further comment. In the absence of any other suggestions (eg possible issues with plugins or anything else), that an uninstall/reinstall doesn't seems to fix it and the fact that 2.18.3 works fine on my 32bit laptop and on another available 64bit desktop, seems this will remain in the realm of the unexplained and may need to do a reformat of system to sort it. Not really my idea of an optimum solution but if all else fails....

Comment: are the files available to the public for testing? and what OS you are using win/linux/mac?

Comment: Thanks for response Kurt. I can prob make them available but I'm 99% sure it's not the file/s. Files work fine on 32bit Windows7 QGIS2.18.3 and 64bit Windows10 QGIS2.14, ArcGIS and applicable browsers. As mentioned 2.18 was working no probs and I'm scratching my head trying to think of things I changed which might have any possible impact. I thought each version of QGIS was pretty self-contained. Did uninstall some old QGIS versions, installed another 3 browsers, added Silverlight, etc but this shouldn't impact, especially in such a particular, bizzare manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you remove all the QGIS files in your user folder as well as uninstalling the QGIS program. Some files are not removed in the standard uninstall and might be causing the problem. I have had to do this on one PC to get GRASS commands working in the QGIS processing toolbox.

Comment: Thanks Grant, looks like that's sorted it. Haven't had to do that before and have been a bit leery about manual removals (have had issues in the past with this causing other problems) . Uninstalled all QGis programs, then removed remaining .qgis2 folder from User and remaining .dll's from Program Files. Will play around with it to check. Cheers.

Comment: I just noticed the following which is along same lines:         shttp://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1