# Save As not working in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I tried to save my project under a new name ("Save as"), as I often do. However, the screen just sort of blinks; then stays the same and does not allow me to enter the new name, etc.. I have upgraded to the latest version of QGIS. I tried doing this with an earlier version of my project (saved under a different name) and it worked ok. Any idea what's the matter with this file, or what I need to do?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gy2448bdzj9zzw/Print%20composer%20scale%207200%20a.qgs?dl=0) is a link to it.

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh3x4480urs4esb/Print%20composer%20scale%207200.qgs?dl=0) a link to the previous version, which did not have this problem.

Comment: could you precise which version of Qgis did you installed and what is your OS ?

Comment: I just updated to the current version, 2.18.11.

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: I would unninstall QGIS and install it again. I have QGIS 2.18.11 in my computer and I don´t have that problem.

Comment: Can you add which data sources you have in your project? Do they work in a newly created, empty project? If yes, you can compare the project files in any text editor. Maybe you can upload the project files somewhere.

Comment: Did you uninstall 2.18.10 before installing 2.18.11? When I try to install latest version(2.18.11) I get a warning that older one will be uninstalled.

Comment: Ernesto--I tried that. Did not help. Note that after uninstalling, the program continued to be listed in Windows/settings/apps. However when I tried uninstalling again, it said it could not find it. So I rebooted and reinstalled; however, when I initiated that I got the message that QGIS 2.18 was already installed. I pressed "ok" to "reinstall". After reinstallation, the problem remained.

Comment: Andre—I have many data sources of various types. Other projects, such as earlier versions of the one I'm using, work fine. It's only this latest version of my project that has this problem. (However I don't want to have to go back to an earlier version.)

Comment: Andre--I'm not clear on what you are suggesting as far as comparing project files. I made many changes to the current version after "saving as" the new name. However, I have edited my question above to include links to the faulty program file, and one to the earlier non-faulty version. I will appreciate anything you might be able to discern...

Comment: and copying manually with file explorer and trying to work with this file?

Comment: Mazu--Is part of your comment (above) missing? I don't understand what you are suggesting...

Comment: Without the data sources your projects don't load here, but the composer sheets are created. Comparing your project files with WinMerge, it seems that only print composer items have changed. Maybe 26 composer sheets are just too much for your RAM. My best advice is to make copies of your project file, removing all but one composer sheet, using a good text editor like notepad++. Then you see which sheet causes the hangup. Alternatively, you can swap file contents with WinMerge from the working to the non-working project one-by-one.

Comment: Andre—I'm quite sure that I at least moved a number of labels around and drew some lines, in addition to making print composer sheets. However, as an experiment I made a copy of the file; opened it; and deleted all my print composers. Did not fix the problem. I then removed all data layers that I have changed recently. Still did not fix the problem. Then removed all layers in the project. Still did not fix. (See next comment)

Comment: I don't know anything about using text editors for changing program files, etc.. Sounds over my head. Is it something non-technical people can do?

I can tell you that all the layers I've been changing are at this link, if that's of any use—
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/14znspokfbg4pjj/AABHCspNbikUhZjKLbqdDU8sa?dl=0

Comment: @TVZ - Make sure after you uninstall QGIS that you also delete the `.qgis2` folder (if it exists) and any related registry keys ([this post might help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1)). Hopefully this can help you do a clean install. An alternative could be to save the project via the **Python Console** using `QgsProject.instance().write(QFileInfo("path/to/project.qgs"))`. Note that you may first need to import _QFileInfo_ using `from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo`.

Comment: I obliterated everything relating to QGIS by use of Revo Uninstaller. After reinstalling, I found that it even evaporated my spatial bookmarks.

However--I still cannot "save as". ..

Comment: Make sure this is not your Dropbox fooling you. It looks like all datasources are in a subfolder named "Dropbox".

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion, Andre, but I have been using "save as" to  make backup copies of this project file for years. Suddenly the "save as" function just stopped working for it. Other earlier versions still work, including the "save as" function. (???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that using a colon ":" in a project title causes problems (at least under windows). I think because the title is suggested as filename, the colon causes the "save as"-dialog to some kind of crash due to the colon presenting a disc-name like c:\Windows...

I don't know if this or a similar problem is an issue under other operating systems than windows.

Funny thing is that if you use a colon in the title of an already existing qgs-file, the "save"-button still works.

Workaround: Save the project without colon in the title and insert the colon to the title-tag of the gs-file with a text-editor. After that you can re-open the project, do changes to the project and use the "save"-button!

Answer (score 6):

Open the file with a Text editor like Notepad++,  the title tag is set to

> Pt O Cult Resource Map @ 1:7200

The problem seems to be with that. Changing that line to say "Resource" and saving the file allows you to do "Save As" when its opened from QGIS.

EDIT: Added picture

[image]

Comment: Don, I totally don't know what I'm doing, but I downloaded & installed Notepad++; I then opened my project file. The second line was, 

<qgis projectname="Pt O Cult Resources Map @ 1:7200" version="2.18.11">

I changed "Pt O Cult Resources Map @ 1:7200" to simply "Resource". I then saved the file and opened it in QGIS. It still would not "save as". Did I understand you correctly and do what you intended? By the way, when I close QGIS, I get a "Crash dumped" message.

Comment: The third line is what I changed to "Resource". I edited my initial answer to highlight the line I changed. You might wanna download a fresh copy and try that again.

Comment: My projects usually have an empty title and projectname. So I doubt these entries have any influence on the saving.

Comment: @AndreJ, that's what I thought as well. But figured I will open his file and take a look at it. I got the same flashing response when I attempt a "Save As" on his original document. 

After changing that line and saving the file. The "Save As" worked. So, it's either the problem gets fixed by me messing with the qgis file or a combination of the special Character and colon is causing the problem for @ TVZ.

We might not know the cause of the problem. I opted to share what fixed the problem with him.

Comment: @TVZ, glad to hear that did it for you as well. In case you are wondering how I found that line, I used Microsoft's Process Monitor (ProcMon for Short). I had that running alongside QGIS during the "Save As". I then filtered out all the captures except for the QGIS ones. ProcMon captures a lot.

A createfile action captured by Procmon from QGIS seemed to be faulting on the title. I changed that and bam it worked.

Comment: Hey @TVZ, mark this answer as the solution, for posterity =).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but was able to save as normally once I deleted the "Project Title" out of the Project Properties section. If you entered a title for the project, just delete it and then try saving.