# Getting back Processing Toolbox?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Processing Toolbox missing after I copied a python script from the Scripts folder to my local folder, and QGIS crashes when I try to active the "Processing" under the Plugin Manager

Re-installation also doesn't work! QGIS crashes when I try to activate it using Plugins Manager

---

It looks like, no one has encountered this problem!!!

There is something getting saved somewhere, or some settings getting saved somewhere, these are stopping the Processing Toolbox getting activated even after repeated installations. Cleaning of all the folders also doesn't help. Installing of stable versions also doesn't solve this problem.

If some source code is available where the Processing plugin within the Plugin Manager can be changed, perhaps might solve the problem. Developers may please help!

Otherwise, the only solution, to my mind,  appears to be to reload the OS (in my case, Windows 64-bit) and install the QGIS application if one really wants to work with the Processing Toolbox!

---

Interestingly, when I added another login account in this PC, the Processing Toolbox is coming in the QGIS in this new login account! However, I did not install QGIS in this login account separately. This shows some settings got permanently changed in the previous login account where the Processing Toolbox still doesn't appear!

Comment: Did you try removing left over files from folders and the registry [mentioned here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1-on-windows-vista) ?
And did you completely remove Phyton as well?

Comment: @sn1ks         Thanks a lot. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this same crash after working with Python script. The best solution, aside from a fresh install of Windows, is as you have stated. Create a new user profile in QGIS and the processing toolbox will be available again. This is a workaround, but will save a lot of time when compared to reinstalling the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the OS is not the answer, that's like using explosives to scratch an itch.

As stated in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/466256/2856), a new profile will work.  But to save recreating your profile and reinstalling plugins and recreating settings, you can try to fix it by removing the broken script.

Use QGIS to open the current profile folder:

[image]

Go into the processing/scripts sub-folder and delete/move the broken script.